Column Error in Power Apps
I have an app that is connected to a SharePoint list and in this app, I want it to be an editable grid. So, I put the controls in a gallery.

Now I am trying to update the SharePoint list when changes are made in the gallery with this code. The controls giving errors are the Combo Box (the square rectangles) which I used for "Person or Group" column of my SharePoint list

Application Owner: {
            '@odata.type': "#Microsoft.Azure.Connectors.SharePoint.SPListExpandedUser",
            Claims: "i:0#.f|membership|" & ComboBox2.Selected.Mail,
            Department: "",
            DisplayName: ComboBox2.Selected.DisplayName,
            Email: ComboBox2.Selected.Mail,
            JobTitle: "",
            Picture: ""
        }

As you can see in the picture, it keeps giving that error no matter what I tried.
Any guidance would be appreciated!

What is the items property of the combo box control, office 365 users connector OR SharePoint person column choices?

@GaneshSanap-MVP the items property of the comboBox control is Office365Users since i want to search and select name from my organization

The comboBox items property has this formula Office365Users.SearchUserV2({searchTerm: Self.SearchText, top:50}).value

Are you passing JobTitle and Picture properties as well in value object?

Yes i am also passing both. They seem to be covered by the error popup
